# MVC 4 Simplemembership

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

I am upgrading a site to MVC 4 and the new simplemembership is killing me.. I am not sure if I am just being stupid but I cannot seem to get UserName from a stored UserId.

In mvc 3 with asp membership I used the following in Razor views where item.CreatedBy is stored Guid:-
**"@Membership.GetUser(item.CreatedBy).UserName"**

What is the equivalent Razor syntax to work with SimpleMembership when itemCreatedBy is now an int.

I am trying to do something like :-
**@GetUserNameFromId(item.CreatedBy)**

All help and pointers gratefully accepted.

many thanks for your time and help

Glyn

Comment: you can even use aspnet membership provider in MVC4, thats what I did when I upgraded my project from MVC2 to MVC4.

Answer (score 2):

By default, MVC 4 uses SimpleMembership which is not compatible with the older MembershipProvider.  If you haven't modified the Account controller & models, you could try to copy it from a fresh MVC 3 app and replace the existing ones in MVC 4 and see if that helps. Here's a link I found useful from  [geekswithblogs.net](http://geekswithblogs.net/Aligned/archive/2012/08/30/mvc-4-authentication.aspx)